Breaking multiple summations of terms in single term summations
I have a question which is a follow-up of a previous one: Break summation of terms in summations of each term.
I noticed that using Distribute on a summation (Sum) can indeed break a summation of terms in summations for each term. Now, my problem is that this does not work well when I have more than one summation, such as:
From \begin{align}2\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2(-t_{l}t_{x} + t_{l}^2t_{x}) + 4\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2(t_{l}t_{x} - t_{l}^2t_{x})+4\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2(\frac{D_{l}D_{x}}{t_{x}} - t_{l}^2t_{x})&\end{align}
where I would like to obtain something like:
\begin{align}-2\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2t_{l}t_{x} + 2\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2t_{l}^2t_{x}+4\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2t_{l}t_{x} - 4\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2t_{l}^2t_{x}+4\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2\frac{D_{l}D_{x}}{t_{x}}-4\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2t_{l}^2t_{x}&\end{align}
which, ultimately, would lead to the cancellation of all terms in this example.
My issue here is:

How can assure that Distribute works on all summations (not just one).
After breaking the summations, do Mathematica automatically cancel out the terms?

This is how I would write the first expression in Mathematica:
2*Sum[Subscript[a,l]^2 (-Subscript[t, l] Subscript[t, x] + (Subscript[t, l]^2  Subscript[t, x])), {l, L}] + 4*Sum[Subscript[a, l]^2 (Subscript[t, l] Subscript[t, x] - (Subscript[t, l]^2  Subscript[t, x])), {l, L}] + 
 4*Sum[Subscript[a, l]^2 ((Subscript[D, l] Subscript[D, x] / Subscript[t, x]) - (Subscript[t, l]^2  Subscript[t, x])), {l,L}]


Use a set of replacement rules implementing some simplification rules:
 expr = Sum[Subscript[a, l]^2 (-Subscript[t, l] Subscript[t, x] + (Subscript[t, l]^2 Subscript[t, x])), {l, L}] + Sum[Subscript[a, l]^2 (Subscript[t, l] Subscript[t, x] - (Subscript[t, l]^2 Subscript[t, x])), {l, L}];

Then,
expr /. {Sum[a_, x_] :> Distribute@Sum[Expand@a, x]}
% /. Sum[-a_, x_] :> -Sum[a, x]



Thanks. Could you explain what is the meaning of the command. It works for the reproducible example I provided, but not for the actual equation I am working with, which include one more summations.

@user29859 You'll need to provide more examples in the OP if you want something more robust.  The first line is a replacement rule that takes each instance of a sum, expands its summand (to change something like a(b+c) into a*b + a*c) and applies Distribute to it. (ReplaceAll (or its infix form /.) scans an expression for a pattern and replaces it.) The second rule is a replacement rule that pulls out a negative sign from the sum. For more info (and examples), look at the documentation page for ReplaceAll.

Thanks this helped a lot! I am going to update my question then, since I also have a factor of 2 to expand.

One way
e = Sum[Subscript[a, 
       l]^2 (-Subscript[t, l]   Subscript[t, 
         x] + (Subscript[t, l]^2  Subscript[t, x])) // Expand, {l, 
    L}] + Sum[
   Subscript[a, 
       l]^2 (Subscript[t, l]   Subscript[t, 
         x] - (Subscript[t, l]^2  Subscript[t, x])) // Expand, {l, L}]
Distribute[#] & /@ e


